# How to end this statement in java

Tags: java

I cant even end this ending statement without error exist

```
import java.util.Arrays;

BufferedReader dataIn=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String a;
    int n=0;

    int array []= {98,9,212,21,11,49,63,70,100};

    System.out.print("My Values "+Arrays.toString(array));

    System.out.print("\nEnter Number: ");
    a=dataIn.readLine();
    array[n]=Integer.parseInt(a);



    if(array[n]==98) {
        System.out.print("The Index Number is 0");
    }

    if(array[n]==9) {
        System.out.print("The Index Number is 1");
    }
    if(array[n]==212) {
        System.out.print("The Index Number is 2");
    }

    }
     else{
        System.out.print("Error");
    }// how to end this?
// if correct the correct index number will go
// if wrong error

}

}
```

Comment: you may want to clarify what you're doing

Comment: Are you looking for `else if`? I trust you actually have a proper class and method declaration too?

Comment: you have an extra `}` before else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one exta `}` before `else`, and you need `else/if` construction

```
if (array[n] == 98) {
    System.out.print("The Index Number is 0");
} else if (array[n] == 9) {
    System.out.print("The Index Number is 1");
} else if (array[n] == 212) {
    System.out.print("The Index Number is 2");
} else {
    System.out.print("Error");
}
```

---

General method for : *value to index* would be :

```
String valueStr = dataIn.readLine();
int value = Integer.parseInt(valueStr);
boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == value) {
        System.out.println("The index number is " + i);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```